# How do git remotes work?

Tags: git, version-control, git-push, git-pull, git-remote

If I have a main project that is version controlled.

I then add a remote for a third party plugin

`git remote add myplugin <url>`

I can then do `git pull myplugin master`

and it just pulls in the changes from that remote.

Now lets say my project is setup as:

```
/
/index.php
/whatever
```

and the remote is setup as

```
/
/whatever.php
```

when I pull in the remote I end up with

```
/index.php
/whatever
/myplugin
/myplugin/whatever.php
```

this is good.

What I am wondering is,
If I make changes to myplugin,

If I issue `git push myplugin master` what is pushed?

Is it going to only push changes in myplugin? 
or does a remote act as a second repository and will commit the entire repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would end up, after a `git pull myplugin`, in `/myplugin/whatever.php` only if the remote repo already contained `/myplugin/whatever.php` (not juut `whatever.php`)

Adding a remote means pulling all its history and merging it into your repo, or pushing your commits from *all* your repo into the remote (not just the changes from your local '`myplugin`').

What you are describing (pushing only the changes from 'myplugin', or pulling commits only in 'myplugin') is called **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

```
 git submodule add url/myplugin myplugin
```

That would add a directory myplugin, in which you would find a second nested Git repo acting like you describe in your question.
It isn't just a new remote, but a submodule url for including in a subdirectory another repo at a specific SHA1.

Answer (score 0):

The remote does act like a second repository because it is one ... when you issue a push command GIT will copy what has been modified over to the remote effectively bringing it back in line with your local repository.

If what you are asking is whether the push will traverse into sub directories then the answer is yes.

If you are asking whether changes which have not yet been committed to your local respository will be pushed to the remote, then the answer is no.